# Singleton implementation using Factory pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton, factory

Since singleton pattern has a number of potential problems, I heard the pattern is getting deprecated in the real industry. So I have implemented a single instance using Factory Pattern and I want to hear from all of you guys if this implementation does not violate any SOLID principle.
Any feedbacks are highly appreciated if you think my new implementation causes another side effect.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Logger;

class LoggerFactory {
public:
    Logger & getLogger();
};

class Logger {
private:
    Logger() { std::cout << "Logger Constructed" << std::endl; }

    friend class LoggerFactory;

public:
    Logger & operator<<(std::string message) {
        std::cout << "[log.txt] " << message << std::endl;

        return *this;
    }
};

Logger & LoggerFactory::getLogger() {
    static Logger * logger = nullptr;

    if (logger == nullptr)
        logger = new Logger();

    return *logger;
}



int main() {
    LoggerFactory aa;

    auto x = aa.getLogger();
    x << "1st output";

    auto y = aa.getLogger();
    y << "2nd output";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point. Absolutely nothing will change if you make `getLogger` a static member of `Logger`, getting back to a classic singleton. Introducing `LoggerFactory` seems pointless, a mere busywork.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Thanks for your response. Then do you have any idea to implement an single instance using factory pattern alternatively? 'static' keeps me from coming up with a novel solution rather than using the singleton pattern.

Comment: I think this is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you allow only a single instance of `Logger` to exist, then that instance is a singleton, by definition, no matter how much glitter and lipstick you put on it. You can't say "I only want a single instance of class `X`, but somehow it shouldn't be a singleton." Frankly, I don't understand the goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah,,, @IgorTandetnik, I agree with you. Let me clarify what I'm trying to figure out and get back online afterwards. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with your statement

> Since singleton pattern has a number of potential problems, I heard the pattern is getting deprecated in the real industry.

I guess you are referring to the Double-Checked Locking Problem (DLCP). This was been well described in Scott Meyers and Andrei Alexandrescu paper: [C++ and the Perils of Double-Checked Locking](https://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf).

The main topic here was thread safe design and usage. For single-threaded code, there will not be a problem with the singleton pattern.

So no big community like the industry will deprecate this pattern. There are still many use cases that require a singleton. Maybe some coding rule in some company does not allow it.

And, DLCP is very old. With new C++ versions, it is completely fixed. Thread safe versions are available. You may look at [here](https://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/).

Now to your code.

This is not a factory pattern. This is a pure, but more complicated, singleton. You are always returning the same instance. So, singleton.

And, that's the sad story, your implementation has the DLCP and is not thread-safe.

Sorry . . .